# Как сделать бесконечное нажатие лкм

Tags: c++

Нужно нажать на лкм в той позиции в которой она находится

```
int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: это не уровень c++, а скорее ОС

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    RECT lpRect;
    POINT pt;
    HWND hwnd;
    for (;;)
    {
        GetCursorPos(&pt);

        hwnd = WindowFromPoint(pt);
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &lpRect);
        pt.x = pt.x - lpRect.left;
        pt.y = pt.y - lpRect.top;
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELONG(pt.x, pt.y));
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELONG(pt.x, pt.y));
    }
}
```